# Should [url-format] be merged with [url] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Does the [url-format](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-format) tag cover anything that the [url](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url) tag does not? Many questions that are tagged with [url-format] are also tagged with [url] - unnecessarily I expect ([url] alone would be sufficient).

Therefore, should the [url-format] tag be merged with [url]?

Comment: FYI [you can propose your own tag synonyms](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). I agree with you, though, and if there are no objections then I'll make `url-format` a synonym of `url`.

Comment: @Christofian - I agree too.

Comment: @Christofian: Ah yes, thanks for the reminder. I wasn't sure, however, whether you have the power or preference to merge and delete redundant tags, over and above creating synonyms? Although, I guess synonyms are perhaps the preferred action in this instance?

Comment: @w3d synonyms are the preferred course of action in this instance: there's no need to merge or delete them in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[url-format](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-format) is now a synonym of [url](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url).